# CakePHP How do I display all table field names

Tags: cakephp

New to CakePHP, so be gentle...

I'm trying to loop through a table to display all the read-only fields (labels and values).
In my edit function, I get the table

```
$this->set('invoice', $this->Invoice->read(null, $id));
```

In my view, I want to loop through the entire table schema and output the field names and values as labels like fieldName: value

```
Invoice Number: SVC00158
Invoice Date: 03/03/12
```

There are 37 fields in this table. I would rather not have to manually code for every one. I know to retrieve the input fields like this

```
echo $this->Form->input('purchaseOrderNumber');
```

but I can't seem to find a 'read-only' attribute for the input() method. Hope that makes sense.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: why displaying inputs (readonly) if they are not supposed to be edited? you could just print out the values in a dd list etc, coudnt' you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could loop through the schema and output it like that:

```
// assumes $result contains model data
$schema = $this->Model->schema();
foreach ($schema as $field => $attrs) {
  echo $result['Model'][$field];
}
```

Comment: Here's the solution I found. Taking me awhile to refresh php skills. foreach ($invoice as $tableName) {
    foreach ($tableName as $fieldName => $fieldValue) {
        echo $fieldName; ?> &nbsp; <?php
        echo $fieldValue; ?> <br /> <?php
        
    }  
}

Answer (score 1):

just write:

```
<?=$this->Form->inputs();?>
```

Comment: nice one, but how to exclude a particular field?

Answer (score 0):

If you are a beginner I suggest you look into Cake Bake (it will "bake" all your files from the console).
I mean the views, controllers, and models based on you current db schema so that will it for you and even apply some styling to it.

I hope that helps